# How to detect a CMenu visiable or not in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm making a right click menu in my application. And I want to check whether the menu is shown or not. But I read the Microsoft docs of `CMenu` and found that there is no way to make it. How to get the menu state, and is there any way to get the menu disappear event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system sends a [`WM_ENTERMENULOOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-entermenuloop) message to a menu's owner window whenever a menu is about to be shown, and a [`WM_EXITMENULOOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-exitmenuloop) message after it has been dismissed.

Those messages map to the [`CWnd::OnEnterMenuLoop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onentermenuloop) and [`CWnd::OnExitMenuLoop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onexitmenuloop) message handlers that your code can override to keep track of the menu state. The `bIsTrackPopupMenu` argument is set to `TRUE` for a popup menu.